# Как образуется придаточное предложение?

Tags: сложное-предложение, недопустимая-метка

Почему в придаточном предложение - глагол стоит в прошедшем времени, хотя говорим о будущем.
Пример - Он хочет, чтобы она "была" здесь завтра.

Answer (score 1):

*Он хочет (что?), **чтобы** она была здесь завтра.*

Также: *Он хочет, **чтобы** она завтра пришла.*

Это  СПП с придаточным **изъяснительным предложением**, для связи используется союз ***ЧТОБЫ***.

***ЧТОБЫ*** обозначает **ирреальное** действие, так как в его состав входит частица ***БЫ.*** Ирреальное действие на самом деле не происходит: это **возможное** или, как в данном случае, **желаемое** действие.

Глагол здесь в форме **сослагательного** наклонения. Собственной глагольной формы у этого наклонения нет, поэтому используется форма **прошедшего** времени и частица ***БЫ***, в том числе в составе союза.

Таким образом, желаемое действие относится к **будущему**, а форма **прошедшего** времени.

**Подробно о наклонениях** можно почитать **[здесь](https://studfile.net/preview/2378058/page:8/)**

Значение сослагательного (условного) наклонения выражается **аналитически:** глагольная форма на –л- (совпадающая с формой прошедшего времени) и частица бы (б). Правда, частица бы только с формами на –л- является показателем сослагательного наклонения.

Сослагательное наклонение **не имеет форм времени и форм лица**, но имеет **формы рода и числа**. Во множественном числе формы рода **нейтрализованы.**

Answer (score 0):

> [Сослагательное наклонение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E,%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B.) образуется с помощью сочетания глагола в
> **прошедшем** времени с неизменяемой частицей бы или в сочетании частицы
> бы с неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитив). В сложных предложениях
> частица бы может быть частью союза **чтобы**